# Allocation data to students

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qopyT.jpg)Good Day!.

I have list of cases from a my report and give the cases to each student in equally
Have few conditions 
1. Student A will handle only special cases. where the len of case# is more that 6, which are call as special case and the max student A can do is 25 cases.
Example :

```
STUD_Loc 1  STUD_Loc 1  Case ID Len Dup Student Name
ST  TGG E16946-1    8   E16946  Student A
MI  FRE E16946-2    8   E16946  Student A
```

2. Reset cases can be assigned to all other student equally. if there a duplicate found that should be assgined the same student at any row o

```
ST  ITL D17514  6   D17514  Student B
LA  PBM D17514  6   D17514  Student B
```

example case file attached.

Need a excel formal or VBA to get it resolved.
as of now i doing it manually and it take near 3 hrs.
Please help

Comment: output : STUD_Loc 1 STUD_Loc 1 Case ID Len Dup Student Name
NY SDK C31554-1 8 C31554 Student A
LA MIL D08453P 7 D08453 Student A
AT HEL B03103P 7 B03103 Student A
ST ADL D07864P 7 D07864 Student A
MI BNE D10943P 7 D10943 Student A
SE LYT D03942P 7 D03942 Student A
CH MEB D19149P 7 D19149 Student A
DE SYD D24488P 7 D24488 Student A
NY WAR D00008 6 D00008 Student C
LA SPS E07035-13 9 E07035 Student A
AT SSV E08183P 7 E08183 Student A
ST TGG E16946-1 8 E16946 Student A
MI FRE E16946-2 8 E16946 Student A
SE BGK E16972P 7 E16972 Student A
CH SIN E16991P 7 E16991 Student A

Comment: HI! Can you post a screenshot of the Excel document instead of posting the values ? Did you try to write a formula? If so, can you show it here?

Comment: Posted with Image.

Comment: So If I understand your question correctly, you have the Case Ids, student names, and maximum number of cases a student will be assigned (in the small table to the right), and you want to automatically fill the column "Student Name" with names of students based on your criteria. Correct?

Comment: NVJ7, Yes your are almost, I have case nos, the list of students and i do not have any max vale apart from one student. Student A will get only 25 case a day to max. reset case can be allocated to other. its not mandatory to be 25 for each.it may be +- no problem . but for A 25 -27 is max  Say I have 100 case and 5 student included A. A will get 27 other cases will be disturbed equally about 19 cases each.(4 student).

Comment: Posted an answer below.. let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a VBA function for your first condition: Assign only special cases (greater than 6 digits) to Student A and also not more than 25 cases.

The below function will run correctly only when the case id's are in the first column (Column A) and student names are to be put in the third column (Column C) of your Excel sheet.

Note: Your worksheet should look like this in order for the following code to run. [image: Excel sheet]

You can also edit the code to put the column of your choice. For example, put "C" instead of "A" for case ids (since the case ids are in column C in your screenshot)

```
Sub Fill_Student_Names()

    ' Count number of cases assigned to Student A
    Count_StudentA = 0

    ' Loop through the Case Ids
    HowFar = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To HowFar

        ' Get length of case id
        Length = Len(Range("A" & i).Value)

        ' If length is greater than 6, assign it to Student A
        If Length > 6 And Count_StudentA <= 25 Then

            ' Put Student A in the Student Name column
            Range("C" & i).Value = "Student A"

            ' Increment the count variable
            Count_StudentA = Count_StudentA + 1

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Code to remove duplicate rows and put the duplicates in a "Duplicates" column (Column D).

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()

    ' Sort the id column in descending order
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Sort key1:=Range("A:A"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

    MsgBox ("Sorted")

    ' Loop through the id column and match first six digits of each pair of consecutive ids
    HowFar = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
    Dim PrevCell As Range
    Dim ThisCell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 3 To HowFar

        Set ThisCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)

        Set PrevCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(i - 1, 1)

        ' Compare the cell values
        If (Left(PrevCell.Value, 6) = Left(ThisCell.Value, 6)) Then

            ' Take the id and put it in the duplicates column
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i - 1, 4).Value = ThisCell.Value

            'MsgBox ("Deleting row " & i)

            ' Delete this row
            Rows(i).Delete

            ' Decrease i by 1
            i = i - 1

            ' Decrease the total number of rows by 1
            HowFar = HowFar - 1

            ' Check if HowFar has not become zero or negative
            If (HowFar <= 0) Then
                Exit For
            End If

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: @Mike: Do you want the code for the second condition too? Also you can mark an answer as accepted if it worked for you.

Comment: Yes, If possible: If the case number duplicate , need to assign it to the same again. in example : BBBBB 7 repeat  4 times . I wants one student to handle all the 4 ...

Comment: How do you check for duplicate cases? Exact matches? Or are these two cases considered duplicate: aaaaa and aaaaa-1?

Comment: cond: If First 6 characters match each other in the enter column.

Comment: @Mike: Okay. I will post a macro after a few hours.

Comment: HI NVJ, I tried in lookup concept. not working properly. Could you please help me with your code.

Comment: What lookup concept? Which part of the code do you not understand?

Comment: Trying to use Vlookp in a column and updated with the result. But I having issue while running. Needed multiple columns.

Comment: Updated a new image how i am try now.
=COUNTIF(A:A,VLOOKUP(A40,A:A,1,0))

Comment: Hi, I've added a sub to remove duplicate case id's and put the duplicate's in Column D. You will need to run this remove duplicates function before running any other function otherwise your sheet will get messed up.

Comment: @Mike: One more sub remains: The one which will assign the remaining case ids to the remaining students. Do you want code for that as well?

Comment: NVJ: Thanks for your updated. i have done it ... Thanks again.

Comment: @Mike: If the answer helped, you can mark it as the "Accepted" answer. Thanks.